# self.tableView reloadData is not working to vertically center my label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    Movie *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = movie.title;
    cell.subtitle.text = movie.subtitle;

    cell.subtitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.subtitle sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

I am calling `reloadData` from two places. One is from the end of a `loadInitialData` function, which is called from `viewDidLoad`.

A second one is being called from `viewDidAppear`, although this is inconsequential to my problem, because it existed before it and exists without it.

I initially load 3 rows of sample data, with titles and subtitles. Now what happens is my subtitle text is vertically centered when this window first launches. If I grab the table and scroll is high up, all of a sudden my `[cell.subtitle sizeToFit]` goes into action, and my text goes to the top vertically, which is desired.

So my issue is... why is the text vertically centered from the beginning? `reloadData` doesn't work either. When I return from adding a new row, all rows but the newly added row are vertically aligned to top as they should. The new row is incorrectly vertically centered.

Why doesn't this work? Everything seems good. New data is added etc. Via `NSLog` statements, I have verified `numberOfRowsInSection` is immediately called after `reloadData` is called.

So why does the aligning of the text vertically to the top not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the UITableViewCell has not yet been layed out and so it does not have a size yet.  Try doing the sizeToFit in this UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am not sure this will work, but it worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I should have mentioned that I tried this as well, and it didn't solve my issue either. I'm really quite stumped on this one.

Comment: Take a look at the frame of the cell and contentView to see if they are even sized correctly in the initial call to cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[cell setNeedsLayout];` before you return the cell so it will layout the cell before presentation.

Comment: I tried this and also setNeedsDisplay right before returning the cell, to no avail.